# Use dynamic api route in axios and use input to render a table in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an app, where I'm using a API, which need to have dynamic route (not sure, if I'm using the right terminology), using that API, I need to get input from the user and based on the input, I have to render the table.

The route is going to be like,
URL = http://localhost:8080/creds?id={my_id}

My code is -

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const baseURL = "http://localhost:8080/creds?id=";

const Demo = () => {
    const [data, setData] : any = useState([]);
    const [input, setInput] : any = useState("");
    
 useEffect(() => {
        const getData = async (my_id) => {
            const endpoint = `${baseURL}${my_id}`;
            const response = await axios.get(endpoint)
            setData(response.data)
            console.log(data) // this shows the output json, but I cannot use it outside the useEffect
        };
        getData(input);
    }, []);

 const handleInput = (e: any) => {
        let value = e.target.value;
        setInput(value);
    };
 const handleClick = () => {
        getData(input)
    }

return (
     <div>
             <input type='text' value={input} onChange={handleInput} />
             <button onClick={handleClick}>search</button>
     </div>
    )
}
```

First error is I cannot use getData, ts says it cannot find it.
How to use this function, outside useEffect?
I want to use the json, which I can see when I
`console.log(data)`
I can't use it as I require.

If you need anymore clarifications, please let me know.

Comment: Why do you have setData(response.data) and console.log(data). Why do you log different variables response.data and data?

Comment: console.log(data) is to check whether is my state getting updated when I do setData(response.data).

Answer (score 1):

you made a mistake, you defined `getData` inside of the `useEffect` callback and this makes your function only accessible within the function scope.

to solve the problem define the function outside the `useEffect` callback and you'll be able to use it anywhere in the component.

Comment: I tried that too, but when I do that, I noticed data I get is not updated, every time I give input, and click on search, it loads the data for previous input.

Comment: I don't get it! okay define it outside the useEffect and add in the deps the input, still something lost in the code or something I cannot understand.

Comment: Input in not an array, it's a string.

Comment: I know that! I meant that add the input "string" in the dependencies array

Comment: When I do that, it tries to take the first value from the JSON and throws an error,
uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined(reading 'date')

Answer (score 0):

There were so many things wrong with the approach.
I have created a `http-common.ts` file, which contains **axios.create**. The axios.create method allows you to create a customized Axios instance with default configuration options.

Made the requests for all the APIs in `apiService.ts` file. And created type for all payload required. API was graphQL API. It was kind of easy to interact it with. Didn't need to make request in useEffect hook.

If anyone has any similar doubt, leave your comments. I'll be happy to answer.